# Spring 3.2 annotation autowiring with multiple constructors

Tags: spring, constructor, autowired, required

Spring docs:

> Only one annotated constructor per-class can be marked as required, but multiple non-required constructors can be annotated.

If I have one autowired constructor, all is fine. If I have two or more autowired, but required=false annotated constructors, all is fine. But if I mix them in a way, such that there is one or more required=false constructor autowiring annotations and exactly one with the required=true, it throws an exception.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Invalid autowire-marked constructor: public annotationconfig.SomeBean(annotationconfig.AnotherBean). Found another constructor with 'required' Autowired annotation: public annotationconfig.SomeBean(annotationconfig.AnotherBean,annotationconfig.AnotherBean[])

Is this expected behavior? Am I missing something about how Spring dependency injection works? If this is normal, why is this a problem for Spring, why can't it handle a setup like this?

Comment: Could you post your source code?

Comment: You can always fall back to annotating the field instead of the constructor marking the field annotation as required=false and lazy loading the variable. HTH

Comment: `@Component public class Account { private Card card; private AtmCard card1; @Autowired(required=true) public Account(Card card) { System.out.println(" in constructor"); this.card = card; } @Autowired(required=false) public Account(Card card, AtmCard card1) { System.out.println(" in setterr"); this.card = card; this.card1 = card1; } }`

Error 
`Error creating bean with name 'account': Invalid autowire-marked constructor: public Account(Card,AtmCard). Found constructor with 'required' Autowired annotation already: public Account(Card)`

Please help with this

Comment: we have to make both the contructors as (required=false) then spring will resolve the dependencies accordingly

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the reason for that behavior is that if one of the constructors have `@Autowired(required=true)` then it must be called (because it is required) and because only one constructor can be called per object instantiation then **what is the point of having other constructors with** `@Autowired(required=false)`?

They won't be autowired anyway, because one of the constructors is already required and must be called. They can still be called without using Autowired mechanism, but in that case `@Autowired(required=false)` annotation is unnecessary.

Comment: `@Component
public class Account {
 private Card card;
 private AtmCard card1;
 @Autowired(required=true)
 public Account(Card card) {
  System.out.println(" in constructor");
  this.card = card;
 }
 @Autowired(required=false)
 public Account(Card card, AtmCard card1) {
  System.out.println(" in setterr");
  this.card = card;
  this.card1 = card1;
 }
}
`

Error
`Error creating bean with name 'account': Invalid autowire-marked constructor: public Account(Card,AtmCard). Found constructor with 'required' Autowired annotation already: public Account(Card)`

Please help witthis

Comment: @mike_m So whats the difference of having only an constructor autowired vs an autowired required?

Comment: @Maxrunner Default value of parameter **required** is **true**. So **@Autowired** and **@Autowired(required=true)** are the same.

Answer (score 5):

Spring 5 docs:

> Only one annotated constructor per-class can be marked as required,
>   but multiple non-required constructors can be annotated. In that case,
>   each is considered among the candidates and Spring uses the greediest
>   constructor whose dependencies can be satisfied, that is the
>   constructor that has the largest number of arguments.

Although one constructor is required, spring might use the other constructors if dependancies are sesolved;